# Android mini drop down as show below

Tags: java, android

Sorry I am a beginner in android, I was searching for solution that I will able to achieve that on the below
[image]

In the picture there is a drop down windows where I have click on the calculator icon. May I know what is this called, do your have the tutorial or code that can send me to achieve that thanks

Comment: you can use a PopupWindow for that.

Comment: Check out this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html  You may need to customize the popuu window for your specific requirement

Comment: You should try the [Layout Inspector](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-inspector) if you want a definitive answer.